# "Send me reset password instructions" not working with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I've been modifying the Devise views, and much to my surprise when I checked out the `Forgot Password` view, and then hit a registered email address and clicked `Send me reset password instructions', I received this:

[image]

Here's the server log:

```
Started POST "/users/password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-18 00:13:14 -0400
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"uVUzOM4xJcbJSl5uLHgV7vuXnUjw8FsBgLptoedq4cw=", "user"=>{"email"=>"andrew@gmail.com"}, "commit"=>"Send me reset password instructions"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'andrew@gmail.com' ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."reset_password_token" = '96b5adaa30ec048962aa6cbc67c3538af1b0dd36d8aa1a929b9de6ec9b92483b' ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `reset_password_token`
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "reset_password_token" = ?, "reset_password_sent_at" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 1  [["reset_password_token", "96b5adaa30ec048962aa6cbc67c3538af1b0dd36d8aa1a929b9de6ec9b92483b"], ["reset_password_sent_at", Tue, 18 Mar 2014 04:13:14 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Tue, 18 Mar 2014 04:13:14 UTC +00:00]]
   (5.0ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb (1.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 57ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):
    2: 
    3: <p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.</p>
    4: 
    5: <p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @token) %></p>
    6: 
    7: <p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
    8: <p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>
  app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_devise_mailer_reset_password_instructions_html_erb__2519734817603171421_70315561035180'
```

What am I doing incorrectly, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the installation devise tells you that you need to at least copy the following

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

to `config/environments/development.rb`

Devise needs that for the mailer.

See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started for more information

Comment: I'm testing the request on a controller spec and needed exactly that line. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Devise needs some additional configuration in order for the password reset via e-mail to work. It needs a host to send the e-mail from, in addition to an email account and password for actually sending the reset e-mail.

http://blog.codeschool.com/post/32745236583/re-generating-forgot-password-emails-with-devise has a good tutorial on getting the reset password email working.

Comment: Do not just past link, give explanation, it will help  Louis93 to understand the problem.